# Append Lighting Setups?

Tags: lighting, append, asset-browser

Is there a way to append lighting setups *that keep's the light positions?* Marking lights as assets or appending them drops all position data so you loose the orientation and arrangement. Looking for a quick, non-HDRI way to try out different lighting setups.

Answer (score 2):

The safer way to append assets or groups of assets is to put them into a collection and append the collection.

If, after appending, something is out of location, probably there was some parenting or constraint that wasn't appended.

Comment: Awesome! That works. Thanks!!